# How to use Eventemitter to broadcast an event from a parent to children

Tags: angular, components, angular2-directives, eventemitter

I have a component which is instantiated multiple times using `ngFor`. The component tag is wrapped inside a directive tag. I want to use `EventEmitter` to broadcast something from the parent directive to the child components. How can I achieve this?

```
@Directive({
    selector : '[elementDir]'
})
export class ElementDirective
{
    constructor(eModel:ElementModel)
    {            
    }
    @Output() updatePosition = new EventEmitter();

    @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event']) onMouseDown(e) 
    {       
         this.eModel.elements[1] = {left : e.clientX, top : e.clientY};
         this.updatePosition.emit(1);
    }
}
```

Component:

```
@Component({
    selector : 'outline',
    template : `
       <div class="outline-v"></div>
       <div class="outline-v right"></div>
       <div class="outline-h"></div>
       <div class="outline-h bottom"></div>
    `
})
export class OutlineComponent implements AfterViewInit
{
    constructor(el:ElementRef,rdr:Renderer,eModel:ElementModel)
    {            
    }
    ngAfterViewInit() 
    {
        this.changePosition();
    }
    changePosition() 
    {
        let index = this.ElementRef.nativeElement.id.split('_').pop();
        this.rdr.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'top', this.eModel.elements[index].top + 'px');
        this.rdr.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'left', this.eModel.elements[index].left + 'px');
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div elementDir>
    <outline (updatePosition)="changePosition()"
         *ngFor="let el of eModel.elements; let i = index" 
          id="el_{{i}}">
    </outline>
</div>
```

ElementModel is an object of elements with position:

```
{elements:[{left:200, {left:432, top: 244}, {left:600, top: 500}]}
```

In the code example above, I have a wrapper directive `elementDir` which holds `outline` component tags. The feature is simple, every outline components are positioned based on its corresponding top and left info from the ElementModel. Say I click anywhere in the elementDir, 2nd outline element (which is selected in this example) will be positioned to where I clicked. In my real app, selected elements are dynamic. I just wanted to let my child components listen for the parent mousedown position.

Comment: With Angular2 you're not supposed to "broadcast" from parent to child. Data flow : Parent to children. Event flow : Children to parent. So I suggest you give some more details and some code about your pb so maybe we can talk about your architecture.

Comment: Hi Maxime, I added my code. Thanks

Comment: Provide a service in `ElementDirective` and inject it to `OutlineComponent` and use it to communicate between these.

Answer (score 0):

`EventEmitter` does not do any broadcasting. `EventEmitter` is to use template binding to events

```
<my-component (someEvent)="..."
```

For broadcasting use cases use a shared service with observables.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service